# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.transformMatrixToLocal(android.graphics.Matrix)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-transitions, android-graphics

Actually, I use the shared elements transition in my code. The error log caught by youmeng is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.transformMatrixToLocal(android.graphics.Matrix)' on a null object reference
>       at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.null setSharedElementMatrices(null)(ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:505)
>       at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.null moveSharedElementsToOverlay(null)(ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:794)
>       at android.app.EnterTransitionCoordinator$3.null onPreDraw(null)(EnterTransitionCoordinator.java:204)
>       at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.null dispatchOnPreDraw(null)(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.null performTraversals(null)(ViewRootImpl.java:2055)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.null doTraversal(null)(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.null run(null)(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.null run(null)(Choreographer.java:858)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.null doCallbacks(null)(Choreographer.java:670)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.null doFrame(null)(Choreographer.java:606)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.null run(null)(Choreographer.java:844)
>       at android.os.Handler.null handleCallback(null)(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.null dispatchMessage(null)(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.null loop(null)(Looper.java:148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.null main(null)(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.null invoke(null)(Method.java)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.null run(null)(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.null main(null)(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I reviewed the versions of the device, which are not centered, including 6.0, 7.0 and 8.0. And the device models are also not centered.

Here is my code:

```
override fun onLoadUrl(url: String, source: String, imageView: ImageView?, drawableRes: Int) {
        val tabBean = MultiWindowManager.getForegroundTab()!!
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
        var fragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag(tabBean.tabId) as? WebFragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            transaction.show(fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss()
            fragment.loadUrl(url, source)
        } else {
            fragment = WebFragment.newInstance(url, tabBean.tabId, source, drawableRes)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                fragment.sharedElementEnterTransition = DetailTransition()
                fragment.exitTransition = Fade()
                fragment.enterTransition = Fade()
                fragment.sharedElementReturnTransition = DetailTransition()
            }
            transaction.remove(mainFragment)
            transaction.add(R.id.frameContainer, fragment, tabBean.tabId)
            imageView?.let {
                transaction.addSharedElement(it, getString(R.string.shared_recommend))
            }
            transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
        webFragment = fragment
        updateFragmentType(FRAGMENT_WEB)
    }
```

DetailTransition.java:

```java
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class DetailTransition extends TransitionSet {
    public DetailTransition() {
        init();
    }

    public DetailTransition(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOrdering(ORDERING_TOGETHER);
        addTransition(new ChangeBounds()).
                addTransition(new ChangeTransform()).
                addTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
    }
}
```

I expect that I can no longer see this bug.

Answer (score 0):

The google play services may have to be updated on your build system, I ran into a similar issue where the QR scanner would not work until the play services were updated via gradle build and then the similar exception was not there at all.

Comment: that's very curious

Comment: :) 1 is glad to be of service